# Integrate custom Google Map search into website

Tags: google-maps, web

I want to integrate google maps into my website ( seems that part is simple with just an apikey).

What I could not find is how could I do this ?

I have a textbox.
say the map shows location of my home . Now when the users enter someplace in the text box it should show the path form the textbox'place to my home . also should give navigation direction .

One way I thought is to use google params like :

```
saddr= "source address my home "
daddr= " Value of text box "
 eg : http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=loc:24.197611,120.780512&daddr=some address
```

Now will the daddr search only near my place ? or will it search globally ?
Because anyone who wants to finds address to my place will obviously live in my city .
If i specify radius =  param or can I just ignore as google by default would search only to near by location ?

This whole idea is just passing param to maps.google.com so essentially I am not integrating the map to the site in the first place .

Is there a better way I could do this ?

I also found a way to inegrate maps into website : http://phpbox.5gigs.net/2011/04/16/show-visitor-location-on-google-maps/

In this he uses ip and reverses the ip to some lat,lon and places the marker.
Is there anyway I could decode the address to lat,lon with respect to nearby myhome ?
if so I could use that . Also there is one small thing that misses out , I am unable to find how do I show navigation routes like turn left etc etc (mentioned in my comment)

Thank you

Comment: By navigation directions I mean , something like take left after something, head straight to lighthouse etc, that appears on the left side of google maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey I found a gadget that does exactly what I want
http://maps.google.com/help/maps/gadgets/directions/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Wordpress plugin (even if its not a wordpress site). It does exactly what you're trying to do when you click "get directions". Try poking through their code (its fairly simply as far as plugins go) and see if you can't extract what you need.

I know that's not an exact answer, but I hope that helps/ gives you some insight!
http://www.grimmdude.com/simple-static-google-maps-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Thanks I checked it. It merely contructs a url with the params as i mentioned earlier. saddr and daddr. :(